# Solr Search for adjective/noun words

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I am using Apache Solr with edismax, and I am trying to execute a search for the following query: Administrative or executive

when i put these query in double quotes  "Administrative or executive", results are perfect

But when i search for +Administrative +or +executive, solr search for Administrator, executed words in documents.

Any help may be appreciated

schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s,\.;]+"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s,\.;]+"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `executed words in documents`?

Comment: You can use the analysis page +debugQuery=true. In this way you will get the index, query (emulated and runtime) behaviour

Comment: @alexf executed means, executive = executed                                               when i search for "executive" word solr also search for "executed" word in the document